# How to add button to a Frame with Graph in java?

Tags: java, swing

Basically, I have a class which is used to draw Graphs on a frame inside it and it extends JPanel. Iam thinking about a way , to add button to that Panel without Disturbing the present Graph . I used Java Window Builder b`y th`e way

```
package motor_2_package;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GraphingData extends JPanel {

   private static final Stroke GRAPH_STROKE = new BasicStroke(3f);
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawGraph");
private static final int GRAPH_POINT_WIDTH = 12;
final int PAD = 20;

int []data1;//=new int[d.getPartList().get(i).getSaleList().size()+1]; //it         
 returns size of sales list supply
int []data2;//=new int[d.getPartList().get(i).getSaleList().size()+1]; //it 
returns size of sales list sold

int xs,ys;
details t=new details();

public GraphingData(details d,int i,int checker)
{
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");
    btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            MotorPartFrame mf=new MotorPartFrame(d);
            mf.setVisible(true);
            frame.dispose();
        }
    });
    btnBack.setBounds(0, getHeight()-PAD, 89, 18);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnBack);
            //paintComponent(g);
       t=new details(d);
      xs=d.getPartList().get(i).getSaleList().size()+1;

      ys=d.getPartList().get(i).getSaleList().size()+1;
      data1=new int[xs]; //it returns size of sales list supply
      data2=new int[ys]; //it returns size of sales list sold
      data1[0]=0;
      data2[0]=0;
      for(int j=1;j<=xs-1;j++)
      {
          data1[j]=j;
         if(checker==1) data2[j]=d.getPartList().get(i).getSaleList().get(j     
   -1).getSupply();
         else data2[j]=data2[j]=d.getPartList().get(i).getSaleList().get(j-  
  1).getSold();
       }


}

 @Override

 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    // Draw ordinate.


    //now we set x- axis border and y-axis border too
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(PAD, PAD, PAD, h-PAD));
    // Draw abcissa.
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(PAD, h-PAD, w-PAD, h-PAD));
    double xInc = (double)(w - 2*PAD)/(double) (30);
    double scale=( double) (h-2*PAD)/getMax(2);

    //now to write spikes on points

    int mah=30,muh=getMax(2);
    for (int i = 0; i<muh-1; i++) {
        int x0 = PAD;
        int x1 = GRAPH_POINT_WIDTH + PAD;
        int y0 = getHeight() - (((i + 1) * (getHeight() - PAD * 2)) /(muh-1) 
 +PAD);
        int y1 = y0;
        g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
     }

     // and for x axis
     for (int i = 0; i < mah; i++) {
        int x0 = (i + 1) * (getWidth() - PAD * 2) / 30 + PAD;
        int x1 = x0;
        int y0 = getHeight() - PAD;
        int y1 = y0 - GRAPH_POINT_WIDTH;
        g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
     }

     //

     Stroke oldStroke=g2.getStroke();
     g2.setStroke(GRAPH_STROKE);
     g2.setColor(Color.RED);
     for(int i=0;i<xs-1;i++)
     {
         int x1=(int) (PAD+(xInc*data1[i]));
         int y1=(int) (getHeight()-PAD-(scale*data2[i]));
         int x2=(int) (PAD+(xInc*data1[i+1]));
         int y2=(int) (getHeight()-PAD-(scale*data2[i+1]));
         g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

     }

     //now for thesecond plot

     g2.setStroke(oldStroke);      
     g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
     for (int i = 0; i < xs; i++) {
        int x =(int) ((int) PAD+(xInc*data1[i]) - GRAPH_POINT_WIDTH / 2);
        int y =(int) ((int) getHeight()-PAD-(scale)*data2[i] -   
  GRAPH_POINT_WIDTH / 2);;
        int ovalW = GRAPH_POINT_WIDTH;
        int ovalH = GRAPH_POINT_WIDTH;

        g2.fillOval(x, y, ovalW, ovalH);
     }


 }


  private int getMax(int x) {
    int max = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if(x==1)
    {
        for(int i = 0;  i < data1.length; i++) {
            if(data1[i] > max)
               max = data1[i];
         }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0;  i < data2.length; i++) {
            if(data2[i] > max)
               max = data2[i];
         }
    }

    return max;

}



public void createAndShowGui(details d,int i)
{

    GraphingData mainPanel = new GraphingData(d,i,1);

    frame = new JFrame("DrawGraph");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);


   }
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. Use a LayoutManager, e.g. BorderLayout, put the original panel in the center and a panel with the button(s) in the south.
2. You could also draw the buttons yourself, e.g. by putting two filled rectangles on top of each other and some text inside, then you need to save the coordinates and detect mouse clicks in that rectangle.